# The expression "Eat in or take out"

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions

whats the meaning of this expression?
(Eat in or take out)

Comment: If you have seen it on a cooked food shop, it means "You may buy food to eat in the shop/café or to take away and eat elsewhere" - at least, in England. Some other countries use different expressions. NB The title of your question is very confusing - I suggest you edit it to "What does this expression mean?"

Comment: Many UK places have two prices for food, because if you eat the food in the restaurant you have to pay a tax, so the cashier will ask you the question 'Eat in or take out?'.

Comment: More context please. Where did you see this?  See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133807/do-you-want-to-eat-in-or-take-out

Comment: What does your question title mean.  I don't understand "Expressions are good way for words but?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you want to eat in or take out?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133807/do-you-want-to-eat-in-or-take-out)

Answer (score 1):

When you go to a fast food restaurant, like McDonalds, you have the choice to **eat** your food **in** the restaurant, or to **take** your food **out** of the restaurant (to eat at home, for example)

So the server at McDonalds will ask you "Eat in or take out".  It means "Do you want to eat in the building or take the food out of the building".  or, more exactly, "Do you want your food placed on a tray so you can take it to your table, or do you want your food placed in bags so you can carry it out of the building?"